# YUM and dependencies, how do they work

Tags: yum

I would like to install **gcc** on a RHEL 7.4 server and i don't have internet connection on it. For that, i have mounted a RHEL 7.4 iso and configured a yum repository file named LocalRepo to install from cdrom.
When i try to install **gcc** i found the following error:

```
# yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=LocalRepo install gcc
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repository rhel-7-server-rpms is listed more than once in the configuration
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.5-16.el7 for package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp = 4.8.5-16.el7 for package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) for package: gcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-16.el7 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-196.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.17-196.el7 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-196.el7 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
---> Package libgomp.i686 0:4.8.5-16.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:3.1.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-196.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-196.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-196.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.el7 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.28.3-6.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686 (LocalRepo)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (LocalRepo)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

Error: Package: glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686 (LocalRepo)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rpms)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (LocalRepo)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It seems the server has a newer **glib-common** library installed, so i have three questions:
1. There is a way to tell yum to use what's installed, knowing that what i'm installing might now work?
2. There is a way to tell yum to install the required **glib-common** library somewhere else, that allow to install **gcc**?
3. Do you know any work around under my current circumstances? (without internet connection)
Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have another server with access to internet might be easier to do
  yum install (or may need to do reinstall) --downloadonly gcc
Check the level of glib-common - will need to be greater than or equal to your other server.
This will create a file with gcc and dependencies.   Move that file to your server without internet access and do a yum install

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the needed commands to do this?